# Why doesn't the ball have rotational energy after it leaves the ramp?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

I am having trouble solving #13 from [the 2010 F=MA contest](http://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2010/upload/2010_Fma.pdf):

> A ball of mass $M$ and radius $R$ has a moment of inertia of $I = \frac{2}{5}MR^2$. The ball is released from rest and rolls down the ramp with no frictional loss of energy. The ball is projected vertically upward off a ramp as shown in the diagram, reaching a maximum height $y_\text{max}$ above the point where it leaves the ramp. Determine the maximum height of the projectile $y_\text{max}$ in terms of $h$.
>
> [image: ball rolling down ramp]

From $mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}Iw^2$ and the condition for rolling friction $v=Rw$ it is easy to find the speed $v$ of the center of mass of the ball when it reaches the flat part of the ramp.But we need to know something about the rotation of the ball when it reaches $y_{max}$ in order to use conservation of energy again. In the official solution it is assumed that the ball has no rotational energy after being projected off the ramp, but I don't see why this is true.

Comment: It asks for the maximum height which can be obtained. I would say that the rotational inertia needs to be transferred into velocity for maximum height to be obtained.

Comment: @LDC3 if the rotational inertia is transferred into velocity, then by simple conservation of energy, the ball will reach $h$ height again. What actually happens is the rotational energy of the ball will remain constant. Thus it is easy to notice that it will cancel out.

Comment: Solution set here:   https://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2010/upload/2010_FmaSolutions.pdf

Comment: BTW, this turns out to be the "cousin" of a problem I ran into ages ago: throw a uniform-density bowling ball such that it slides w/o any rolling, then, due to friction, rolls without any sliding. Calculate the change in velocity when that happens.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be any rotation when the ball reaches maximum? This is a bad problem.

Comment: @LoveLearning take a look at the correct answer.  There is rotation.  Gummybears is wrong.

Comment: What happened to his answer anyway?

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion here stems from the fact that the author of the question says "In the official solution it is assumed that the ball has no rotational energy after being projected off the ramp" which is clearly not the case.  Perhaps we should add a note to the end of the original question.

Comment: Sorry I meant at the maximum height!

Answer (score 3):

Think about this: how does the ball's rotational speed change between the time it is runs off the end of the ramp and the time it reaches $y_\text{max}$? (What torques are being exerted on it between those times that could change its rotational speed?) When it reaches $y_\text{max}$, what kinds of energy does it have? If you can figure that out then you should be able to see why they solve the problem the way they do.

Comment: This should be a comment.  In general, "hints" are comments, and full solutions are answers.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft except for homework-like questions. The [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) goes through this. (Personally, I consider this an argument in favor of prohibiting homework-like questions from the site entirely, but that's just me.) Anyway, if other people agree this doesn't constitute an answer, I'm fine with deleting it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, David :-)

Comment: @DavidZ: I agree that the homework policy is inconsistent with how the site is supposed to work. Perhaps full *answers* should be allowed but the type of homework-like *questions* should be constrained. I see nothing wrong with giving a full, detail oriented answer to a student who poses a well formed specific question regarding his/her homework. For example, the present question does not ask us to do the assigned problem for OP. Rather, OP asks a pointed question which indicates prior thought. I see no problem with giving a full direct answer.

Comment: @DanielSank let me be clear: giving a full direct answer to the conceptual question the OP is asking is _fine_. Nobody is arguing otherwise. Certainly one could post a more explicit answer to the conceptual question than I did, without it being a candidate for deletion. What is not okay is giving a full answer to the underlying question from the contest.

Comment: Hi @DavidZ, it seems to be a lot of confusion in the comments regarding this problem. Hence I posted a solution attempt, although there is still some algebra left to do. I hope this is OK for everyone?

Comment: @LoveLearning no, the answer you posted is exactly the kind of thing prohibited by our homework policy, because you gave a full solution to the contest question. I'm going to delete it, but feel free to post another answer that doesn't solve the contest question.

Comment: Well how much hint is allowed?

Comment: @LoveLearning According to the homework policy, showing the answer to the contest question is not allowed. Neither is showing so much of the derivation that it's patently obvious how to get to the final answer. (The exact wording is "complete or near-complete solution".) As long as you don't include that, you're fine.

Comment: OK I've edited my answer. Could you have a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20197/discussion-between-david-z-and-love-learning). (edit: oops, didn't meant to click that, but the new version is fine; you need to post it as a new answer, though. Feel free to reply in the chat room if you want.)

Comment: After the ball leaves the ramp the rotational energy is constant (no torque), and at the maximum height the translational kinetic energy is 0, so we have $mgh_1+0.5Iw^2=mgh$. And this gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ denote the vertical position of the lower dashes. Conservation of mechanical energy gives

$$\tag{1}Mgh + 0 + 0  = 0+\frac{1}{2}M v_B^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega_B^2,$$
where the zeros on the LHS represent the fact that linear kinetic energy is zero and rotational energy is zero at the starting point. The zero on the RHS represents the fact that I have defined the potential energy to be zero at $B.$

Notice that as long as there is rolling, there is also the relation (for circular objects) 
$$\tag{2}\frac{v}{R} = \omega,$$ (an easy way to remember this relation is to consider the dimensions of the quantities involved: $\omega$ "is per second" hence we need to "divide out the length" in $v$ by putting the $R$ in the denominator).

Now, think about what happens to the ball once it reaches and moves beyond $B$. Should the ball speed up/down? Should it all of a sudden stop rotating?

You say that the solution says that as the ball reaches the highest point (on the right) it has no rotational kinetic energy? Ask yourself if this makes sense. What happens to the rotational energy? Also you might ask yourself what the velocity of the ball should be at the highest point.

Answer (score 1):

Let us perform conservation of energy for the ramp;

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}Iω^2$

given the no-slip condition for rolling friction, $ω=R/v_{cm}$ and moment of inertia $I=\frac{2}{5}MR^2$

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{5}mv^2$

$v_{cm}^2=\frac{10gh}{7}$

Nowhere in the alluded-to solutions is it stated that the rotational kinetic energy is zero upon leaving the ramp. During this period, rotational kinetic energy remains constant due to lack of torque, whilst translational kinetic energy decreases until 0. Thus, only initial translational kinetic energy and final gravitational potential energy remain in this subsequent application of energy conservation.

$mgy_{max}=\frac{1}{2}mv_{cm}^2$

$y_{max}=\frac{5}{7}h$

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to [physics.se]! This nice answer has gotten a couple of [flags](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) because [we aren't a homework help site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/), and too-complete answers to homework-like questions usually get deleted. I think this answer is fine for a question that's several years old, but keep that policy in mind as you look for other places to contribute. Hope to see more of you!

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that!

Comment: No worries! Best wishes, see you around.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the friction is absent, ball(it's a solid spherical ball, moment of inertia = (2/5)m*r^2) will slip all the way and will not be able to roll, hence will not rotate, only translatory motion will account for. 
If you had friction on the track, Energy would surely have been distributed between kinectic translational and rotational.